# Adjust plot title (main) position

Tags: r, plot

I have been unable to find a way to adjust the (vertical) distance between plot and main title in R using par. In this example:

```
plot(1, 1, main = "Title")
```

I can adjust the position of the axis titles using:

```
par(mgp = c(2.5, 1, 0))
```

But I see no way to similarly adjust the main title. I am aware that more manual control is possible using `title` or `mtext`, but I assume that there is a way setting the title distance using par as well, which would be more elegant for my purposes.

Comment: I noticed that the third entry of mar indirectly affects the position of the title. For example par(mar=c(x,y,0,z)) should produce a title really close to the plot, while par(mar=c(x,y,2,z)) should produce a title that is more distant. I found no better way to do that without mtext and title.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

We can use `title()` function with negative `line` value to bring down the title.

See this example:

```
plot(1, 1)
title("Title", line = -2)
```

[image]

Comment: That one definitely works - thanks for that. I was looking for a way of doing it using par, which would allow setting up several parameters in one line and then just getting the desired plots without the need for manual adjustment. Do you know if it is just not possible using par?

Comment: For subtitle (normally drawn under X axis) use `title(sub='Sub title notes', line=2)`. You may need to arrange bottom margin (e.g. increase 2 lines) by `par(mar=c(5+2, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)`.

Answer (score 67):

To summarize and explain visually how it works. Code construction is as follows:

```
par(mar = c(3,2,2,1))
barplot(...all parameters...)
title("Title text", adj = 0.5, line = 0)
```

explanation:

```
par(mar = c(low, left, top, right)) - margins of the graph area.

title("text" - title text
      adj  = from left (0) to right (1) with anything in between: 0.1, 0.2, etc...
      line = positive values move title text up, negative - down)
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
par(adj = 0)
plot(1, 1, main = "Title")
```

or equivalent:

```
plot(1, 1, main = "Title", adj = 0)
```

`adj = 0` produces left-justified text, 0.5 (the default) centered text and 1 right-justified text. Any value in `[0, 1]` is allowed.

However, the issue is that this will also change the position of the label of the x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: `However, the issue is that this will also change the position of the label of the x-axis and y-axis.` ... This can be fixed by simply calling a separate function for the title using `title(main = x, adj = ...)`