# Adjust plot title and sub-title in base R

Tags: r

How do I get base R plots title and subtitle to mimic ggplots? I'd prefer everything left aligned, nothing in bold, and subtitle to be directly below title.

I'd also like a little more space between everything. Maybe my newline `\n` 'hack' is the best way to accomplish this?

```
plot(mtcars)
title(main = "I want main title NOT bold and left aligned\n\n", 
      sub = "Sub title should be under the main title left aligned")
```

[image: r_titles]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355410/adjust-plot-title-main-position and https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-text-to-r-plot/ could be useful

Comment: maybe `help(mtext)` can be helpful

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on Cettt's suggestions, what about using `mtext` as follows:

```
plot(mtcars, oma=c(2, 3, 5, 2))
mytitle = "I want main title NOT bold and left aligned"
mysubtitle = "Sub title should be under the main title left aligned"
mtext(side=3, line=3, at=-0.07, adj=0, cex=1, mytitle)
mtext(side=3, line=2, at=-0.07, adj=0, cex=0.7, mysubtitle)
```

The `adj=0` option requests left alignment.
The `line=` options define the vertical position of each title, counting outwards from the border of the plot top margin.
You can play with the `at=` option to move the titles horizontally as wished.

Note also the use of the `oma=` option in the `plot()` call so that there is enough space to place the titles above the pairs plot.

Here is the plot:
[image]